# Stability of $\dot u=f(u,\epsilon)=-u+u^2-\epsilon u$, $u,\ \epsilon\in\mathbb R$

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the vector field
$$\dot u=f(u,\epsilon)=-u+u^2-\epsilon u,\ \ \ \ u,\ \epsilon\in\mathbb R$$
The aim of this exercise is to discuss the stability of the fixed points of the field. In the following I give my approach.

We have $f(0,0)=0$. The fixed points are
$$u=0, \ \ \ u=\epsilon+1$$
For the stability we calculate:
$$f_u(u,\epsilon)=-1+2u-\epsilon$$
So:
$$
f_u(0,\epsilon)=-1-\epsilon
\begin{cases}
<0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \epsilon>-1 \\
>0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \epsilon<-1  \\
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
f_u(\epsilon+1,\epsilon)=1+\epsilon
\begin{cases}
<0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \epsilon<-1 \\
>0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \epsilon>-1  \\
\end{cases}
$$
Then $u=0$ is stable for $\epsilon>-1$, unstable for $\epsilon<-1$ and $u=\epsilon+1$ is stable for $\epsilon<-1$, unstable for $\epsilon>-1$.

[image]

Comment: Yes. And if $\epsilon=-1$? :-)

Comment: @Did ... ehm :-)

Comment: What? This is direct...

Comment: @Did. Oh, ok I have $\dot= u^2$... it should be a bifurcation point!

Comment: So... stable or unstable?

Comment: A saddle point? Maybe it is neither stable nor unstable...

Comment: Huh? Did you draw a phase diagram? This yields the answer *immediately*...

Comment: Hence, it should be unstable, because in any neighborhood of $\epsilon=-1$ there are unstable branches (dashed line).

Comment: No neighborhood of $\epsilon$ is involved. Simply, if $\epsilon=-1$, the differential equation is $\dot u=f(u)$ with $f(u)=u^2$. Now, $f>0$ everywhere except at $0$ hence solutions starting from $u_0>0$ near $0$ diverge to $+\infty$ while solutions starting from $u_0<0$ near $0$ converge to $0$. Thus...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29939/discussion-between-mark-and-did).